# Retrieve text between third and fourth commas

Tags: excel, trim

I'm trying to get the text between third and fourth commas.

Text is : 00025,22,Sarf Зэkэюlarэ,CD DISK 25 ADET,150.99.001.01.105,30.06.2015,

I need the "CD DISK 25 ADET" out of the text.

Comment: sorry it's third and fourth commas...

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", REPT(" ", 999)), 2999, 999))
```

Comment: [Glad you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*3, LEN(A2)))

is better i guess

Comment: tbh, it really doen't matter how many spaces you insert in place of commas just so long as there are sufficient to separate the sections adequately. Those `999`'s could `99` or `999999` and it wouldn't make any measurable difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

=MID(A2,FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,(FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1))+1,(FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,(FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1))+1))-(FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,(FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+1)+1)+1))+1))

but i am sure there is an easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",3))
```

***Position of 2nd 3rd etc instance of character***

https://exceljet.net/formula/position-of-2nd-3rd-etc-instance-of-character